# Jira not auto-adding users from OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, jira, openldap

I have a number of users set up in OpenLDAP.  I have set up Jira to Read only, Local Groups and set up the auto-add group to jira-users.  However, it does not automatically add any users to the group, instead telling them they don't have permission to log in.  The users aren't in any groups in OpenLDAP (and I would prefer not to add a new group and modify other software to create them into the group).  It seems that Jira doesn't bother adding the user if they aren't in any groups at all.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: In the end I had to set up my other software to create users into the jira-users group.  Love to know a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not. When you configure Jira in such a manner it should solely rely on OpenLDAP server as all user rights/permissions/groups setting functions are delegated to the server.

If you create a `jira-users` group in OpenLDAP it should work fine.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that.  What is the purpose of the auto-add to group setting, then?

Comment: I am not completely familiar with this feature. Can you provide a reference to it in the documentation?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I guess I don't get notifications!  See the section titled "Adding Users to Groups Automatically" on this page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+an+LDAP+Directory  I could never get that to work.